# Deleted local master branch

Tags: git, github

I was sloppy and was deleting a whole bunch of local branchs, instead of doing them one by one after each one was done, and I accidentally deleted my local master branch on git. The project is still up at github.  So how do I resolve this issue?  If it helps I'm using terminal on a mac.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`git branch master origin/master`

Comment: Thank your for your prompt answer.

Answer (score 2):

Master branch is not a special branch, it can easily be created just as any other branch.

```
git branch master ## creating master branch
git checkout master  ## switching to master branch
git branch -u origin/master ## setting up remote tracking branch
```

or

```
git branch master ## creating master branch
git branch -u origin/master master ## setting up remote tracking without switching
git checkout master ## switching out to master
```

or all in one

```
git checkout -b master origin/master ## create, set up tracking, switch
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple do,

`git checkout master`

Git will pull master branch if you don't have it in local.